# Loop causes a string index out of range error - why?

Tags: python

This part of the code is for a school project and will be converted into pseudocode so I can only use syntax which is common to both python and pseudocode. This part checks password strength based on characters used in the password.

```
if (password_accepted == True) and (username_accepted == True):
    lowercase_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    uppercase_array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    number_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    security_level = 0
    lowercase_present = False
    uppercase_present = False
    number_present = False
    for i in range (0, len(password_to_be_checked)):
        for i in range (0, len(lowercase_array)):
            if password_to_be_checked[i] == lowercase_array[i]:
                lowercase_present = True
        for counter in range (0, len(uppercase_array)):
            if password_to_be_checked[i] == uppercase_array[i]:
                uppercase_present = True
        for i in range (0, len(number_array)):
            if password_to_be_checked[i] == number_array[i]:
                number_array = True
```

Its giving me the error on this line:

```
  if password_to_be_checked[i] == lowercase_array[i]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: I don't think you've looked into the behavior of `for`-loops well enough. By the way, what's with the weird requirement of it also qualifying as psuedo-code? You can immediately write more idiomatic Python (and psuedo-code) by removing the `== True`, since boolean expressions are automatically compared to `True`. And remove the silly parentheses as well.

Comment: What do you think happens to the `i` of your outer `for` loop when you use `i` (twice) for inner `for` loops as well? Why do you have a for with a `counter` thats not used inside its code?

Comment: I've got to do it for pseudocode for my GCSE in computer science, which doesn't require any real code but my school is making me do it in python as well as pseudocode

Comment: Generally speaking, the Python interpreter isn't going to be able to execute psuedo-python code.

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from

```
for i in range (0, len(number_array)):
    if password_to_be_checked[i] == number_array[i]:
         number_array = True
```

Your password is probably shorter then `10` wich is the max number `i` will get for the `number_array`

Your code then tries to access the character `n` of your password that only has `n-1` characters in it -> **Index-error**

Alternative solution:

```
def check(s):
    lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
    # uppercase = lowercase.upper() # better then doing the adhoc upper() multiple times
    numbers = "0123456789"
    lowercase_present = False
    uppercase_present = False
    number_present = False
    for c in s:
        lowercase_present |= c in lowercase # same as += for + but for logical OR
        uppercase_present |= c in lowercase.upper() # adhoc ToUpper
        number_present |= c in numbers
        if lowercase_present and uppercase_present and number_present :
            break; # no need to test any further, got all 3
    print(s, " contains number: ", number_present, " lower: ", lowercase_present, "upper: ", uppercase_present)



check("lower")
check("lowerUpper")
check("lowerUpperNumber")
check("!!!")
```

Python can do so nice things without resorting to indexing directly....

You could even go as far and use `string.isnumeric()` or  `isalpha()`  - you can create your own litte helper functions for pseudocode that do this test